# How to show confirm popup before close app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I put close icon in AppBar for close app. when I press close icon I want to show confirm popup before close app.

```
  class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future<bool> showExitPopup() async {
      return await showDialog(
            //show confirm dialogue
            //the return value will be from "Yes" or "No" options
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Exit App'),
              content: Text('Do you want to exit an App?'),
              actions: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                  //return false when click on "NO"
                  child: Text('No'),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
                  //return true when click on "Yes"
                  child: Text('Yes'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ) ??
          false; //if showDialouge had returned null, then return false
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
        title: Text('My App'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.close),
            onPressed: () {
              return WillPopScope(
                  onWillPop: showExitPopup, //call function on back button press
                  child: Scaffold(
                      appBar: AppBar(
                        title: Text("Override Back Button"),
                        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                      ),
                      body: Center(
                        child: Text("Override Back Buttton"),
                      )));
            },
          ),
        ],
        leading: new Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I create function `showExitPopup()` in class and use `WillPopScope` at line `onPressed: ()` but when I press close button it not show confirm popup. How to show confirm popup before close app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should wrap the parent scaffold as the child.

```dart
WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: showExitPopup,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          title: Text('My App'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.close),
              onPressed: () {
              },
            ),
          ],
          leading: new Container(),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

the `WillPopScope` only handles for the system back or the default back button callback, not for custom close button. If you want to close your app using the custom button. You just need to call the `showExitPopup` inside `onPress`.